# fopen in PHP times out under large loads

Tags: php

I was trying to find out why fopen in the below code returns "false" - it says "Connection timed out" error for some of the requests when the number of requests is so large. For e.g. if I send 50K requests, only 40k+ were successful and for remaining requests, I get the following error. If number of requests were only 8K, then successful requests will be around 7.5K. The more I load the server, the more number of failed requests I see.

Error:

> PHP message: PHP Warning:  fopen(https://hidden-for-privacy-and-security-reasons): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /data/www/xxxxx.php

```
 $url = "https://hidden-for-privacy-and-security-reasons";

$optional_headers = array("authorization: something valid is here","cache-control: no-cache", "content-type: application/json");

  $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;

  $context = stream_context_create($params);

  $fpointer = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);

  if($fpointer !== false)
  {
      $resphdrs = stream_get_meta_data($fpointer);
      if ($resphdrs["wrapper_data"][0] == "HTTP/1.1 201 Created")
      {
       error_log("SUCCESSFULLY received = " .$resphdrs["wrapper_data"][0], 0);
      }
      else
      {
       header($resphdrs["wrapper_data"][0]);
       error_log("Some ERROR occurred= " .$resphdrs["wrapper_data"][0], 0);
      }
   }
  else 
  {
      header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
      error_log("500 error received", 0);
     // echo $get_error_header[0];
  }
```

For all the missing or failed requests mentioned above, I see that it lands in the OUTER else part (500 internal error) and syslog giving me connection timed out errors. What's the trick I'm missing?

Comment: Did you try curl instead? http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: Not yet.. But I read some articles that said curl is capable of doing multiple requests in a single call, but instead i need it to make a single request in a single call and i dont mind if it uses multiple threads to invoke the same call.. but it has to be one-request = one-call

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on curl.. It seems to be working and I wish I hadn't overlooked it a few days ago. It would have saved me a couple of days. Better late than never, it's now working with curl.. no timeouts.